# spring boot HttpSecurity{403} exception on ajax post an array to RequestMapping

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

i am trying to post an array from ajax call but getting error {http 403} may be due to

.and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessdenied");

but the similar requests i am making from other pages using Model are working fine , Infact i tried to made all pages public still same error coming

```js
function selectedboxes() {
  var rows_selected = table.columns().checkboxes.selected()[0];
  console.log('data' + rows_selected);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/admin/ggtables',
    data: {
      rows_selected: rows_selected
    },
    type: "POST",
    sucess: function(data) {
      if (data.status == "SUCCESS") {
        console.log('submitted sucessfully');
      } else {
        console.log('Error Msg' + data.message);
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error while submit');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="#frm-alert" action="#" method="POST">
  <table id="alert" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input name="select_all" value="1" id="alert-select-all" type="checkbox" /></th>
        <th>Server</th>
        <th>Process</th>
        <th>Is_Active</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>
<p>
  <button id="add" onclick="selectedboxes()">Send all selected processes</button>
</p>
```

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/ggtables",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ggstablePage(@RequestParam(value= "rows_selected[]",required=false) Integer[] alerts) {    
        System.out.println("posted callled");
     // System.out.println("===="+alerts);
      return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

this is ajax request is not reaching request mapping , and seems like WebSecurityConfig sending exception, but i am not able to see any error/exception on console.

chrome is showing 403 and i am getting access denied page in return, just to add , i am able to see value in th ajax variable on chrome console

please help , is there any way to check why the error is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved after adding below.

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

//jQuery
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
```

or disable csrf .csrf().disable().cors()